# Parse JSON using lkJSON

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-7, instagram-api

I have a JSON file which I need to parse and extract one value.

```json
{
  "user": {
    "pk": 25025320,
    "username": "instagram",
    "full_name": "Instagram",
    "is_private": false,
    "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fmad3-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/295f9e76d3c26fdf613d7856e7b43348/5B4F495B/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14719833_310540259320655_1605122788543168512_a.jpg",
    "profile_pic_id": "1360316971354486387_25025320",
    "is_verified": true,
    "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
    "media_count": 5164,
    "follower_count": 233901016,
    "following_count": 187,
    "biography": "Discovering — and telling — stories from around the world.",
    "external_url": "",
    "usertags_count": 144,
    "hd_profile_pic_versions": [
      {
        "width": 320,
        "height": 320,
        "url": "https://instagram.fmad3-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/893534d61bdc5ea6911593d3ee0a1922/5B6363AB/t51.2885-19/s320x320/14719833_310540259320655_1605122788543168512_a.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "hd_profile_pic_url_info": {
      "url": "https://instagram.fmad3-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8ae8a89c80ff4722eeab592b685276cb/5B5D40A1/t51.2885-19/14719833_310540259320655_1605122788543168512_a.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 320
    },
    "has_highlight_reels": true,
    "auto_expand_chaining": false
  },
  "status": "ok"
}
```

I want to extract and send the value of `hd_profile_pic_url_info.url` to `Memo2` using the [lkJSON](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/) library, [Instagram API](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/25025320/info/) and code below to achievie [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj5xb.jpg).

```pascal
var
  sJSON: string;
  js, Items, Item: TlkJSONbase;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  sJSON := Memo1.text;
  js := TlkJSON.ParseText(sJSON);
  for I := 0 to Pred(js.Count) do
  begin
    Items := js.Child[I].Field['user'];
    for J := 0 to Pred(Items.Count) do
    begin
      Item := Items.Child[J];
      Memo2.Lines.Add(VarToStr(Item.Field['hd_profile_pic_url_info'].Value));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please revise and correct the JSON content. This is incorrect/erroneous.
You can check it here(https://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot that `hd_profile_pic_url_info` is another object containing `url`, `width`, and `height`, so you need to go down one more time. Here is an example of how this should be done properly.

```
var
  js : TlkJSONbase;
begin
  js := TlkJSON.ParseText(Memo1.Text);
  if Assigned(js) then
  begin
    js := js.Field['user'];
    if Assigned(js) then
    begin
      js := js.Field['hd_profile_pic_url_info'];
      if Assigned(js) then
      begin
        js := js.Field['url'];
        if Assigned(js) then
           Memo2.Lines.Add(VarToStr(js.Value));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this function :

```
function ChildValueStr(AChild: TlkJSONbase; const Name: string; DefaultValue:
    AnsiString = ''): {$IF CompilerVersion>=26}WideString{$ELSE}AnsiString{$IFEND};
var
  tmpIndex: integer;
  tmpStr: {$IF CompilerVersion>=26}WideString{$ELSE}AnsiString{$IFEND};
begin
  Result:= DefaultValue;
  if IsNil(AChild) then exit;

  tmpStr:= (AChild as TlkJSONobject).{$IF CompilerVersion>=26}getWideString{$ELSE}getString{$IFEND}(Name);

  if tmpStr = '' then
  begin
    tmpIndex := (AChild as TlkJSONobject).IndexOfName(Name);
    if tmpIndex <> -1 then
      Result := (AChild as TlkJSONobject).getString(tmpIndex);
  end
  else Result:= tmpStr;
end;
```

so with your code, you can use it :

```
var sJSON: String;    
js, Items, Item: TlkJSONBase;    
I, J: Integer;    
begin    
    sJSON := Memo1.text;    
    js := TlkJSON.ParseText(sJSON);    
    for I := 0 to Pred(js.Count) do
    begin
        Items := js.Child[I].Field['user'];          
        Memo2.Lines.Add(ChildValueStr(Items, 'hd_profile_pic_url_info'));
    end;   
end;
```

I hope this can help u

Comment: i have error on function line code   if IsNil(AChild) then exit;

Comment: Sorry, isNil is my function how test object function IsNil(Sender: TObject): boolean, begin Result:= (not Assigned(Sender)) or (Sender=nil); end;

Comment: `IsNil` is superfluous, `not Assigned(Sender)` is already [sufficient](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Assigned).

Comment: `Sender = nil` is also sufficient. [`Assigned()` was introduced to handle method pointers](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/assigned-or-not-assigned-that-is-the-question-28836), which `IsNil()` does not take as input.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to parse JSON without use external components is the free online service https://jsontodelphi.com/

You paste the JSON text and it generate a unit with delphi classes to parse the text without problems. Better if the JSON text is complicated.

In this case, the code to access to the value is simpliest:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  root:TRootClass;
begin
  root := TRootClass.FromJsonString(Memo1.Lines.Text {your JSON text});
  // The caption get the URL of the pic
  Caption := root.user.hd_profile_pic_url_info.url;
end;
```