# Delphi 2007 JSON array of string to TStringList

Tags: json, delphi-2007

Embarcadero introduced JSON types with Delphi 2009, but I'm using Delphi 2007 without these JSON types.

I'm wanting to process a JSON string being an "array of strings" into a TStringList object.

e.g.
["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]

I guess it's string token type of processing ..

Comment: There is a third party delphi unit that might be useful for this .. uLkJSON .. I will have a look at this.

Comment: Related link as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653204/parse-json-using-lkjson

Comment: There are many 3rd party JSON libraries that are compatible with Delphi 2007. Just search around and pick one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party Delphi unit that might be useful for this:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/

```pascal
uses uLkJSON;

var
  AString:String;
  AStringList:TStringList;
  jsonbase,Items : TlkJSONbase;    //as per 3rd party unit uLkJSON
  I: Integer;
begin
    AStringList:=TStringList.create;
    AString := '["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]';
    jsonbase := TlkJSON.ParseText(AString);
    if Assigned(jsonbase) then
    begin
        for I := 0 to Pred(jsonbase.Count) do
        begin
            Items := jsonbase.Child[I];
            AStringList.add(Items.Value);
        end;
    end;
    Result := AStringList;
end;
```